# Why dose the mongodb returns circular object even though the inserted object is not a circular one

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, express, mean-stack

I Am a newbie in MEAN-stack applications, I was trying to create one social media application in mean-stack. I created UserModel.js file to keep the user whole details which is given below,

UserModel.js file

```
 var Address = {
 pincode : "",
 post : "",
 city : "",
 district : "",
 state : "",
 country : "",
 };

var Privacy = {
public :true,
friendsOnly : false,
friendsOfFriendsOnly:false,
ImagepostPrivacy : false

};

var Education = {
primarySchool : "",
highSchool : "",
higherSecondary : "",
college : "",
};

var UserModel = {
id : "",
name : "",
lastname : "",
age : 0,
email:"",
phone:"",
username : "",
password : "",
active : true
};

function getUserModel(){
  return{
  userBasicDetails : UserModel,
  userAddress : Address,
  userPrivacy : Privacy,
  userEducation : Education,
  userFollowings : [],
  userFollowers : [],
  userFriends : []
  }
 };

 module.exports.Usermodel = getUserModel;
```

I considered it as a POJO class of java, then In userService.js file I accessed this object and assigned the req.body() 's corressponding values to Usermodel and there I converted this Usermodel object to json and which worked as expected.

code for creating and inserting object for 'users' collection,

```
 var userModel = require("../../../models/UserModel");
 var con = require("../../database/DbConnection");
 var userObject = null;

function registerNewUser(registerdata,callback) {
if(!validateInitialRegisteration(registerdata)){// some validation stuff
    return callback(new Error("Invalid data"));
}else{

    userObject = createUsedrObject(registerdata);
    console.log("object before insertion %j",userObject);// got converted json
    con.database().collection('users',function (err,usersCollection) {
        usersCollection.insert(userObject,{w:1},function (err) {
            if(err){
                console.log("error %j",err);
                callback(err,null);
            }else{
                callback(null,userObject);
            }
        })
    });
  }
}

/**
*This function will make the user collection object
**/

function createUsedrObject(obj){
    var userObject = userModel.Usermodel();
    userObject.userBasicDetails.name = obj.firstname;
    userObject.userBasicDetails.password = obj.password;
    userObject.userBasicDetails.username = obj.username;
    return userObject;
}
```

And I got inserted the object to my 'users' named collection, Then I wrote  function to retrieve data from 'users' named collection

```
 function loginCheck(credentials,callback){
 if(!credentials){
     return callback(new Error("Invalid data"));
 }else{
    con.database().collection('users',function (err,usersCollection) {

        if(err){
            return callback(err,null);
        }
        else{
             console.log("fetched data %j",usersCollection.find()); // here I am getting a log like 'fetched data [Circular]'
            //callback(null,usersCollection.find());
        }

    });
   }
  };
```

expected json i consoled before insertion is given bellow

```
 { userBasicDetails: 
    { id: '',
      name: 'vishnu',
      lastname: '',
      age: 0,
      email: '',
      phone: '',
      username: 'kr.vishnu401@gmail.com',
      password: '1234',
      active: true },
   userAddress: 
      { pincode: '',
        post: '',
        city: '',
        district: '',
        state: '',
        country: '' },
    userPrivacy: 
      { public: true,
        friendsOnly: false,
        friendsOfFriendsOnly: false,
        ImagepostPrivacy: false },
        userEducation: 
      { primarySchool: '',
        highSchool: '',
        higherSecondary: '',
        college: '' },
      userFollowings: [],
      userFollowers: [],
      userFriends: [] }
```

and the collection in db is

```
  > db.users.find({"_id":ObjectId("581ae4994878ad1a84fa0c77")})
  { "_id" : ObjectId("581ae4994878ad1a84fa0c77"), "userBasicDetails" : { "id" : "", "name" : "vishnu", "lastname" : "", "age" : 0, "email" : "", "phone" : "", "username" : "vishnu@gmail.com", "password" : "123456", "active" : true }, "userAddress" : { "pincode" : "", "post" : "", "city" : "", "district" : "", "state" : "", "country" : "" }, "userPrivacy" : { "public" : true, "friendsOnly" : false, "friendsOfFriendsOnly" : false, "ImagepostPrivacy" : false }, "userEducation" : {"primarySchool" : "","highSchool" : "", "higherSecondary" : "", "college" : ""}, "userFollowings" : [ ], "userFollowers" : [ ], "userFriends: [ ] }
```

Since it is in Circular type I am not able to convert this object to json, but the inserted object I converted to json before db operation. I think somewhere I messed the concepts. If you have faced same problem please let me know.

Comment: You posted quite some info while, in fact, what needs to be examined is the INPUT for the TO-JSON conversion. [This site](http://jsonlint.com/) can help you finding out if your input is properly formed to become a JSON object.

Comment: Thank you very much @FDavidov I found that "_id" : ObjectId("581ae4994878ad1a84fa0c77") generating error in json now i need to fix this problem by finding a solution to avoid object id in result data,

Comment: If my suggestion was helpful, you may consider up-voting my comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`usersCollection.find()` is a function that takes a callback

try this instead

```
usersCollection.find().toArray(function(e, users) {
  if (e) {
    return callback(e, null);
  }

  console.log(users);
  callback(null, users);

});
```

Documentation: https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html